# Selector para cada una de las letras de un párrafo

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente css que selecciona perfectamente la primera letra de un párrafo...

```css
p:first-letter {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Esto es un párrafo</p>
```

Pero... ¿Existe algún selector para poder hacer referencia a todas las letras?

Es decir, quiero aplicar ese estilo a todas las letras. Si el estilo lo aplico al párrafo no realiza lo que intento obviamente, necesito que aplique ese estilo a cada letra por separado.

Se que si le pongo a cada letra un span con la letra dentro podría realizarlo, pero si voy a insertar un texto desde php o js por ejemplo tendría que añadirle a cada letra el span y quiero evitar eso

Comment: Mmmm creo que no existe un selector para eso... hasta lo que se... pero puedes hacerlo con JS

Comment: Por cierto, ¿Por qué no mejor seleccionas a toda la etiqueta `p`? `p { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo esta propuesta en la que se recorre cada caracter del párrafo y se envuelve dentro de un `span` con la clase que le da los estilos y al final se agregan los `span` estilizados al párrafo vacío.

El código está comentado. Si tienes dudas, deja un comentario.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  //Capturar el texto del párrafo
  let parrafo = document.getElementById("parrafo").innerHTML;
  //Capturar el párrafo vacío
  let estilizado = document.getElementById("estilizado");
  //Inicializar la variable vacía
  let estilo = '';
  //Recorrer cada caracter
  for (const caracter of parrafo) {
    //Si el caracter no es un espacio
    if(caracter != ' '){
      //Crear un span aplicando la calse que le dará los estilos
      estilo += `<span class="estilo">${caracter}</span>`;
    }
  }
  //Al final se pasan todos los caracteres con su respectivo span al párrafo vacío
  estilizado.innerHTML = estilo;
});
```

```css
.estilo {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="parrafo">Esto es un párrafo</p>
<p id="estilizado"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso que dices nada más se puede hacer con `JS`, no hay ningún selector así en `CSS` creo...

Por ejemplo:

Ponemos un `id` a tu etiqueta.

```
<p id="miParrafo">Esto es un párrafo</p>
```

```
// Seleccionar el párrafo
const myParagraph = document.getElementById('miParrafo');

// Obtener el texto del párrafo y eliminar los espacios en blanco
const text = myParagraph.innerText.replace(/\s/g, '');

// Convertir el texto en un array de caracteres
const characters = text.split('');

// Crear un nuevo array con cada letra dentro de un elemento span
const wrappedCharacters = characters.map(character => {
  return `<span>${character}</span>`;
});

// Volver a unir los elementos en una cadena de texto y asignarla al párrafo
myParagraph.innerHTML = wrappedCharacters.join('');
```

Y en la clase de los estilos, envolvemos solo los caracteres del texto en un elemento `span`

```
#miParrafo span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
}
```